# Python organizing project with extensions like Swift

Tags: python

I am new to python coming from Swift. In Swift I can create a new file and add code to an existing class using the `extension` key word. Does python have a similar way to do this or does all source code need to be in a single file?

I would like to do this to help organize my project.

Answer (score 3):

In Python, functions are first-class citizens. This means that you can assign functions to names just like you assign other values. In particular, you can add a function to a class like this:

```
class Foo:
  def foo(self):
    print('foo')

def bar(self):
  print('bar')
Foo.bar = bar

f = Foo()
f.foo()
f.bar()
```

Note that even though `bar()` is declared globally, it still must take at least one parameter. Traditionally, the first parameter of member functions is called `self` but this is only a convention and is not enforced by the language.

Comment: Just so this doesn't cause confusion, this method only works if the source of the class is available. `object.bar = lambda : 1` will return `TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'object'`

Answer (score 0):

Python will also look in the same director as your base file when using the `import` or `from` keywords.

to build on Code-Apprentice's answer, you can also inherit easily from a class like this (if you wanted to extend the functionality of the `list` class:

```
class NewList(list):  # inherit from the list class
    @property
    def sqrt_len(self):
        return len(self) ** .5

nl = NewList([1, 2, 3, 4])

print(nl.sqrt_len)  # prints "2.0" to stdout
```

You could then put `newlist.py` in the same directory as another `.py` and use `import newlist` or `from newlist import NewList`

A word of caution, make sure there isn't a name collision with your file and the name of another package that you want to use as python will import the files in the same directory first.

Comment: This is really not the same mechanism as OP is describing in Swift. In Swift, one can add additional functionality to an existing class without subclassing. This is just an example of creating a subclass, which is something different.

Comment: Well, yeah. Python doesn't have extensions, so the mechanism will not be the same. I was trying to provide an example of how to execute the same idea (extending the functionality of a class and organizing a project) in Python. Which you can do very simply by inheriting and using local modules.